# Closing apt-get terminal pop-up

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, eula

When I try installing an application on Ubuntu 16.04, I get this IBM EULA pop-up:

[image]

I've tried Ctrl+C, Esc, Enter, still haven't been able to get past this screen.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing F12 on the terminal solved the issue!